# Python TypeError for plotting every Nth value 'unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'method' and 'int''

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, typeerror

I am brand new to coding and Python, and am struggling with plotting something.  So I have two sets of data that I have plot on a map using a gradient (two scatter plots in the red and blue colormaps).

[image: outputted plot of the first two data sets]

```
fig1=plt.figure()
ax=plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND)
gl=ax.gridlines(draw_labels = True, linewidth=0.0, color='gray')
gl.xlabels_top = False
gl.ylabels_right = False
plt.scatter(VFX0,VFY0, c=VFF3, s=2, cmap='Reds')
plt.colorbar(label='High Divergence', shrink=0.6)
plt.scatter(VBX0,VBY0,c=VBF3, cmap='Blues', s=2)
plt.colorbar(label='High Convergence', shrink=0.6)
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')
plt.title('Langrangian Coherent Structures', weight='bold')
plt.show()
```

Now I have a third dataset that I would like to add that plots the latitude and longitude of floats over the other figure.  However, the dataset is so large that if I just plot them all, such as

```
plt.scatter(fframe.lon, fframe.lat, color='k', s=1)
```

all I get is a black figure since there are so many floats.  So, what I would like to do, is take every 10th float and plot that instead.  So I tried to tell it to take the 'fnum', which is the float number, and if it is divisible by 10, then plot that, but ignore everything else.

```
if fframe.fnum.all%10==0:
    plt.scatter(fframelon, fframelat, color='k', s=1)
```

But when I do this, I get an error saying

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-28254189539a> in <module>()
----> 1 if fframe.fnum.all % 10 == 0:
      2     plt.scatter(fframelon, fframelat, color='k', s=1)
      3 plt.xlabel('Longitude')
      4 plt.ylabel('Latitude')
      5 plt.title('Langrangian Coherent Structures', weight='bold')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'method' and 'int'
```

Can anyone help me figure out where my mistake is?

Comment: `fframe.fnum.all` is a method. What did you expect `fframe.fnum.all % 10` to do?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to _call_ it?  `fframe.fnum.all() % 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption that `fframe.lon` and `frame.lat` are lists or unidimensional numpy arrays, you may plot every `n`th point by `fframe.lon[::n]`. E.g. for every tenth point,

```
plt.scatter(fframe.lon[::10], fframe.lat[::10], color='k', s=1)
```